# Element Metrics with Custom collection in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out the best way to organise a bunch of my data classes, given I need to be able to access some metrics on them all at some point.

Here's a snippet of my OR class:

```
public enum status { CLOSED, OPEN }

public class OR
{
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public status status { get; set; }
}
```

Not every OR I initialise will have values for all properties. I want to be able to 'collect' thousands of these together in such a way that I can easily obtain a count of how many OR objects had a value set. For example:

```
OR a = new OR() { reference = "a" }
OR b = new OR() { reference = "b", title = "test" }
OR c = new OR() { reference = "c", title = "test", status = status.CLOSED }
```

Now these are somehow collected in such a way I can do (pseudo):

```
int titleCount = ORCollection.titleCount;
titleCount = 2
```

I would also want to be able gather metrics for the enum type properties, for example retrieve a `Dictionary` from the collection that looks like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> statusCounts = { "CLOSED", 1 }
```

The reason for wanting access to these metrics is that I am building two collections of ORs and comparing them side-by-side for any differences (they should be identical). I want to be able to compare their metrics at this higher level first, then break-down where precisely they differ.

Thanks for any light that can be shed on how to accomplish this. :-)

Comment: Absolutely no need for `IDisposable` here.

Comment: And what is `.TitleCount` supposed to be? Every element has a Title so maybe you meant `.TitleCount(titleToCount)` ?

Comment: I presume it's "non-null title count"? Btw how many properties do your classes have? Does it make sense to have a separate dictionary for each property?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thanks I'll remove IDisposable. `titleCount` is the number of elements with a `title` set. Only 2 of the 3 in the Q are set so I'd like to get the number 2 back. You indicate I can do this with Linq queries?

Comment: @Groo Correct, non-null. I have about 25 properties, what do you mean about having a separate dictionary? For a handful of types that are `enum`, I want to have a dictionary of all the set values and a count of those (like the non-null count of the strings), so when I've built all the ORs from two data sources I can see that one data source has for example one less count of 'CLOSED'.

Comment: Yes, I'll add a sample.

Comment: @deed02392: if you wanted `O(1)` complexity for getting count of all objects which have a title property of specific value, you could have a `Dictionary<string, int>` (or even a `Dictionary<string, List<OR>>` if you also need to retrieve actual instances based on a property value). And then you would have this for all properties which need fast access. Generally all you are doing this way is caching results for faster access, and with caching there is always a compromise between speed and storage which you need to determine based on your actual needs and common scenarios.

Comment: Additionally, if you have 25 properties and all you want is non-null counts for each property, you could simply keep 25 counters and keep track of their counts. The main problem with all these approaches is that is doesn't help with composite queries (e.g. find me all items which have `reference` and `title` properties set to `null`). It's similar to creating an SQL DB index: you have to pick exactly which properties are going to be in a query, if you want to cover the query entirely using the index. Otherwise SQL will do an index seek for covered properties and scan other values sequentially.

Comment: That's interesting @Groo. I don't think I'll need to worry about speed in the scope of this project, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... to 'collect' thousands of these

Thousands is not a huge number. Just use a `List<OR>` and you can get all your metrics with Linq queries.

For example:

```
List<OR> orList = ...;

int titleCount = orList
       .Where(o => ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.title))
       .Count(); 

Dictionary<status, int> statusCounts = orList
        .GroupBy(o => o.status)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: This is amazing! Linq is a thing of beauty.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and download LinqPad. Also, try to confirm to coding standards, properties and types start with a Capital: `Status Status { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers using Linq are absolutely great and really elegant, so the idea presented below is just for posterity.

Here is a (very rough) reflection-based program that will alow you to count the "valid" properties in any collection of objects.

The validators are defined by you in the Validators dictionary so that you can easily change what is a valid/invalid value for each property. You may find it useful as a concept if you end up with objects having tons of properties and don't want to have to write inline linq metrics on the actual collection itself for every single property.

You could weaponise this as a function and then run it against both collections, giving you a basis to report on the exact differences between both since it records the references to the individual objects in the final dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace reftest1
{
    public enum status { CLOSED, OPEN }

    public class OR 
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public status status { get; set; }
        public int foo { get; set; }

    }

    //creates a dictionary by property of objects whereby that property is a valid value
    class Program
    {

        //create dictionary containing what constitues an invalid value here
        static Dictionary<string,Func<object,bool>> Validators = new Dictionary<string, Func<object,bool>>
            {

                {"reference", 
                    (r)=> { if (r ==null) return false;
                              return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.ToString());}
                },
                {"title",
                    (t)=> { if (t ==null) return false;
                              return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.ToString());}
               }, 
               {"status", (s) =>
                    {
                        if (s == null) return false;
                        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ToString());
              }},
             {"foo",
                 (f) =>{if (f == null) return false;
                            return !(Convert.ToInt32(f.ToString()) == 0);}
                    }
            };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new List<OR>();
            collection.Add(new OR() {reference = "a",foo=1,});
            collection.Add(new OR(){reference = "b", title = "test"});
            collection.Add(new OR(){reference = "c", title = "test", status = status.CLOSED});

            Type T = typeof (OR);
            var PropertyMetrics = new Dictionary<string, List<OR>>();
            foreach (var pi in GetProperties(T))
            {
                PropertyMetrics.Add(pi.Name,new List<OR>());
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    //execute validator if defined
                    if (Validators.ContainsKey(pi.Name))
                    {
                       //get actual property value and compare to valid value
                       var value = pi.GetValue(item, null);
                       //if the value is valid, record the object into the dictionary
                       if (Validators[pi.Name](value))
                       {
                           var lookup = PropertyMetrics[pi.Name];
                           lookup.Add(item);
                       }
                    }//end trygetvalue
                }
            }//end foreach pi
            foreach (var metric in PropertyMetrics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property '{0}' is set in {1} objects in collection",metric.Key,metric.Value.Count);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static List<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type T)
        {
            return T.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title count using this linq query:

```
int titleCount = ORCollection
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.title))
                    .Count();
```

You could get the count of closed like this:

```
int closedCount = ORCollection
                     .Where(x => x.status == status.CLOSED)
                     .Count();
```

If you were going to have larger collections or you access the values a lot it might be worth creating a custom collection implementation that stores the field counts, it could then increment/decrement these values as you add and remove items. You could also store a dictionary of status counts in this custom collection that gets updated as you add and remove items.

Comment: Re your custom collection that increments/decrements as I add and remove, this is exactly what I envisaged. But I will only be adding to it and then comparing two collections, so Linq seems to be sufficient. Thanks!